# Certain grid in combination with a responive background

Tags: html, css, gridview, responsive

I would like to have the certain (see attachment) grid developed.

- fullscreen background grey/white
- content is in a max-width grid (width: 1360px)
- content exist of a left and right column (75%/25% width)
- the right column (yellow box) should shift to the right so it's always horizontal centered to the white/grey background (so out of the grid a bit)
- eventually on smaller resolutions everything goes among each other.

I can fix realise this grid with my skills till a certain point. I don't figure out how to center/combine the yellow box centered to the grey/white background.

[image: grid picture]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you provide some example of what you tried so far and what exactly not working

Comment: Thank you Tamit. I'm realising this at the moment via Visual Composer in WordPress, so no customise html. I'm aware of html/css but I'm wondering if this is possible what I want and if someone can give me a direction. Than I can start customise it myself eventually to html and than integrate it to WordPress.